# SQL Server 2008 stored procedure result as column default value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

First of all, thank you guys. You always know how to direct me when I can't even find the words to explain what the heck I'm trying to do.

The default values of the columns on a couple of my tables need to be equal the result of some complicated calculations on other columns in other tables. My first thought is to simply have the column default value equal the result of a stored procedure. I would also have one or more of the parameters pulled from the columns in the calling table.

I don't know the syntax of how to do it though, and any time the word "stored" and "procedure" land next to each other in google I'm flooded with info on Parameter default values and nothing relating to what I actually want.

Half of that was more of a vent than a question...any ideas though? And plz plz don't say "Well, you could use an On-Insert Trigger to..."

Comment: Actually, you need an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to enforce defaults this way, not "on" (`FOR`/`AFTER`) insert.  The only alternative is to have no default and use a stored procedure to do the actual insertion.

Comment: It's probably better to force all inserts to use an SP to do the insertion than mess around with defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to convert that stored procedure to a user-defined function. There are different types of UDF's - the one you're looking at would be the scalar UDF - returning a single value.

So for instance you could create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourDefaultFunction(@Input1 INT, @Input2 VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(100)

   SET @Result = @Input2 + ' - giving: ' + CAST(@Input1 AS VARCHAR(5))

   RETURN @Result
END
```

Of course, yours would be a lot more complicated :-)

Once you've done that, you can define this to be the default for a column of type VARCHAR(100) - either directly when declaring the table, or later on via an `ALTER TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(.......
   SomeColumn VARCHAR(100)    
      CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_SomeColumn 
      DEFAULT (dbo.YourDefaultFunction(417, 'Test')),
   .....)
```

or :

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_SomeColumn 
  DEFAULT (dbo.YourDefaultFunction(4711, 'Test2')) 
  FOR SomeColumn
```

Unfortunately, you cannot pass other columns as parameters to your function when defining it as a default value for a column.

Does that help??

Answer (score 4):

You can't have the default be the result of a stored procedure, it has to be a function. If you can convert the procedure into a function, then you can use that function. If you cannot, then you must use a trigger.

Comment: Yes, a function. Good to know what I was wanting is in some form possible.

You wouldnt be able to provide a simple snippet of how to implement that could you?

Comment: See examples D, J, K and L at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Comment: Awesome, ty everyone for your help! ...I'll keep the trigger solutions in mind too, hoping they arent my only choice in the end.