# Use Stored Procedure as Default Value of a column

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to a use stored procedure as a default value of a column. It's called "dbo.GetAdmin"

Basically, this stored procedure looks up for the user id "admin" and if it doesn't exist, the SP inserts it then returns it as a user record.

Now I want to use this SP as a default value for a column like this :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transaction] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Transaction_From]  DEFAULT ([dbo].[GetAdmin]) FOR [From]
```

But I get this error :

> The name "dbo.GetAdmin" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

In this related post, an user told us that we have to use a function instead of a stored procedure : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2851783/5591761

Because user-defined functions are allowed as a default value for a column.

**But according to the documentation of a function :**

Functions are computed values and cannot perform permanent environmental changes to `SQL Server` (i.e., no `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements allowed).

So, because I have to insert the user if it doesn't exist, I have to use a stored procedure instead of a function. How can I workaround this issue ?

Comment: You have to rethink your design...

Comment: I'm actually designing my database, so yes I can rethink the design, but how ?

Comment: I would use a stored procedure for all inserts into that table, then the SP can create a new user if it is missing. Push that logic closer to the app rather than at a deep database level.

Comment: I always find it **highly dangerous** if a method or stored procedure called `Get(something)` suddenly starts having state changing side effects - like inserting rows into a table. That's just against the **Principle of Least Surprise** - when I get `Get(something)`, my expectation is that it's only **getting** values - ***NEVER EVER*** changing any! (or inserting new ones)

Comment: Ok i see. Thanks for the help !

Comment: You're misreading the documentation as well. You're reading that a function cannot perform DML operations to mean it can't be used in a DML operator; the 2 are completely different things. You *can* use a Scalar function in a `CONSTRAINT` for a column, though they can have a (significant) performance impacts. There's even an example of `CHECK CONSTRAINT` use a UDF in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-of-check-constraints)

Comment: It might help to know what's in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

An insert trigger would allow this if it had to be done. I'm assuming the Admin value does not change per record in the insert should somebody insert more than one record. Otherwise, a loop would be required to execute the procedure for each record. I would think hard about alternatives before doing this. It might be that this has to be done for consistency. Depending upon what the procedure is doing, it might be possible to do a set based query in the trigger by pulling the proc code into the trigger.

For example, trigger code might be something like

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) RETURN -- no inserted records (where clause)

DECLARE @AdminId int -- the same value for all records inserted by statement
EXECUTE @AdminId = [dbo].[GetAdmin]

IF @AdminId IS NULL RETURN -- don't bother updating NULL to NULL

UPDATE t
SET [From] = @AdminId
FROM [dbo].[Transaction] t
INNER JOIN inserted i.record_key = t.record_key -- match each inserted to itself uniquely
WHERE i.[From] IS NULL -- no value was provided upon insert

RETURN
```

Also, error handling can be tricky calling a procedure from a trigger.

If you DBA can insert a record upon request in SSMS without supplying the ADMIN value, then you might not need this.